# Flutter Vscode Debug Console Not Properly Displaying Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am currently following a flutter tutorial on udemy. In the video, the instructor showed us how to debug Flutter application using the **debug console** in vscode. I followed the video, but **realised that my debug console is drastically different from the instructor's.** My debug console does not contain any colors like blue and red and it does not contain the possible links to the error. Here is a comparison

> Instructor's debug console

[image]

> My debug console

[image]

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: are you running your app with the terminal (flutter run) or with the button bar above main in main.dart?

Comment: still, without the links you can still see that your file quiz.dart line 47 is where the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

it is unclear that whether you want your debug console to be exactly same as Udemy instructors or want to know why error message is different from instructor's.

if it is the first case, you do not need to care about whether debug console prints out errors nice and pretty, as long as you see where that error comes from. I guess there should be an extension for flutter error message.

if it is the second case, you need to read error message carefully again

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the **Theme** of your VS Code editor, then debug console will be changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).